# Is having a "Contact us" form in the footer of every page on a website considered good ux?

Tags: usability, website-design, forms, footers

Inside a footer which appears to be constant everywhere on the website, is it best practice to give this option on every single page or should it be ignored on some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea to repeat this form every time you enter a page, because in my point of view if the user wanted to contact you he knows how to find it, but still, you have the responsibility to show it in a good way.

You can put it:

1- The header but try to make it shine beside the header links on the right side. But it in a creative way (ex: Anything? just Contact us) make the contact us link a link or button whatever you feel good implementation.

2- You can include it as a nice looking button in the footer.

3- Also you can use it as a floating button when you click it, it will open a popup with the contact us fields to fill and send.

Good luck,